# AngularJs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following the official angular tutorial, specifically at step 4 where I am trying to reorganize my files so that a feature related code is in a separate module as explained in https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04.

When I define a component in trip-list/trip-list.module.js it works but if I move the definition to a separate file called trip-list/trip-list.component.js, it throws the following error in both Chrome and IE 9.

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module carpoolApp due to: 
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module tripList due to: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
```

Relevant code snippets:

- Html Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="carpoolApp">
<head>
    <title>Isha Carpool App</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>

</header>

<section>
    <greet-user></greet-user> <!-- this works -->
    <trip-list></trip-list> <!-- this works only if I define the component in trip-list.module.js. Doesn't work if I put it in a separate file and include it after loading trip-list.module.js as mentioned below -->
</section>

<footer>

</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="trip-list/trip-list.module.js"></script>
<script src="trip-list/trip-list.component.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

- Javascript: app.module.js

```js
var carpoolApp = angular.module('carpoolApp', [
    'tripList'
]);

carpoolApp.component('greetUser', {
               template: 'Hello, {{$ctrl.user}}!',
               controller: function GreetUserController() {
                 this.user = 'world';
               }
             });
```

- Javascript - trip-list/trip-list.module.js

```js
angular.module('tripList', []);
```

- Javascript: trip-list/trip-list.component.js

```js
'use strict';

// this prints a valid object
console.log('tripList module in component', angular.module('tripList'));

angular.
  module('tripList').
  component('tripList', {
    templateUrl: 'trip-list/trip-list.template.html',
    controller: function TripListController() {
        this.trips = [
            {
                from: 'BNA',
                to: 'iii',
                departureDateAndTime: new Date()
            },
            {
                from: 'iii',
                to: 'BNA',
                departureDateAndTime: new Date()
            }
        ];
    }
});

// this too prints a valid object
console.log("tripList component registered", angular.module('tripList').component('tripList'));
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/w9odyMbzjzUrryfRCeqh - version that works (the component is defined inside the trip-list.module.js itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to send a git PR with a change that worked and that doesn't work, I accidentally made it work. It turns out the problem was that the index.html file didn't have the right EOL (it was in dos format). You can probably see the ^M changes in the diff below. Can't count how many hours I wasted on this!

```
diff --git a/src/main/webapp/index.html b/src/main/webapp/index.html
index fd50422..86d0666 100644
--- a/src/main/webapp/index.html
+++ b/src/main/webapp/index.html
@@ -23,8 +23,9 @@
 <script src="trip-list/trip-list.module.js"></script>
 <!--
 TODO: This doesn't work :(
-<script src="trip-list/trip-list.component.js"></script>
 -->
+<script src="trip-list/trip-list.component.js"></script>^M
+^M

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use setter of the angular module **tripList** as below

```
'use strict';

// this prints a valid object
console.log('tripList module in component', angular.module('tripList'));

angular.
  //modified the below line
  module('tripList',[ ]).
  component('tripList', {
    templateUrl: 'trip-list/trip-list.template.html',
    controller: function TripListController() {
        this.trips = [
            {
                from: 'BNA',
                to: 'iii',
                departureDateAndTime: new Date()
            },
            {
                from: 'iii',
                to: 'BNA',
                departureDateAndTime: new Date()
            }
        ];
    }
});

// this too prints a valid object
console.log("tripList component registered", angular.module('tripList').component('tripList'));
```

Comment: the module is being created in the `trip-list/trip-list.module.js` file, this would overwrite that;  I suspect the question is more why that module isn't being attached to.

Comment: Tried the setter. Doesn't work. Btw, as mentioned before, the same snippet that registers a component, works just fine if I put it in trip-list.module.js. So, am not sure if it has something to do with the code itself.

Comment: can you create a plunker in both the cases!